# How to disallow duplicate vertices in Boost graph?

Tags: boost, boost-graph

How do I disallow duplicate vertices in boost graph?

```
using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::setS, boost::bidirectionalS>;
```

but still I am seeing duplicate nodes in my graph. Shouldn't be enough to `setS` for vertexList be enough?

```
void doGraph() {
      using graph_t =
         boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, std::string>;
      graph_t interference;
      add_vertex("m", interference);
      add_vertex("m", interference);
      // prints 2, why?
      std::cout << "vert #" << num_vertices(interference);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The property bundle is not part of the equality definition for a vertex. The vertex descriptor is, and they are not the same:

```
  auto v1 = add_vertex("m", interference);
  auto v2 = add_vertex("m", interference);
  assert(v1 != v2);
```

If you want to lookup by name, you'll have to add an index for it yourself (use a map/bimap). If you just want named vertices, consider using the `labeled_graph` adaptor (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/graph/example/labeled_graph.cpp). Sadly that adaptor isn't part of the documented library. I wrote several answers that use it in the past.